# Combining queries into a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 joins running doing the same thing (taking information from a nav links table to dynamically add titles to a navbar). At the moment i'm figuring that if i need to add more than 2 nav links it'll mean further headaches down the line, i don't want to keep adding a union for each select statement

```
SELECT header_title
FROM navlinks 
INNER JOIN who_we_are ON navlinks.id = who_we_are.navlinkid
UNION
SELECT header_title 
from navlinks 
INNER JOIN contactpage ON navlinks.id = contactpage.navlinks_id
```

Comment: Or you add a UNION foreach navbar or you add a new subquery foreach navbar whats the difference?

Comment: Where does the header_title come from? It looks like you don't need a union but a simple EXISTS check.

Comment: Headbar title comes from the contactpage and who-we-are tables, both which have a field called 'header_title'. I mean i'm 99% sure there will be better ways of doing this but it was the only way i could think to make a dynamic navbar. I should mention it's running mysql.

Comment: To me the table structure seems wrong/not normalized.  A separate table for each page?  so if you add a What_we_do page you'd have a new table?  That's not the way RDBMS work.  This seems to be more of a NOSQL structure.  The "SitePage" should be the table and in it you list all the attribute data with the pages and then if needed link to a table with different details.  What's the structure for who_we_are and contactpage? So yes, you're right a new union would be annoying; but I think you'd have to do it given the current RDBMS structure.

Comment: fair enough point, the site could maybe do with a refactor. It does seem a bit annoying to have to add a table for each new page. it's my first time trying to make something that also as room to scale so i'm a bit out of my depth. Anyway thanks for the suggestion, i'll go and have a think.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LEFT JOIN` and `coalesce` function.

```
SELECT distinct coalesce(who_we_are.header_title,contactpage.header_title,null)
FROM navlinks 
LEFT JOIN who_we_are ON navlinks.id = who_we_are.navlinks_id
LEFT JOIN contactpage ON navlinks.id = contactpage.navlinks_id
WHERE coalesce(who_we_are.header_title,contactpage.header_title,null) is not null
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d5c85/2

Comment: thankyou i'll give that a bash. I had an idea but is there some way of going into the information_schema data and getting all values from a certain column name, in a sense that would be easier and allow the use case that if i was to create further pages i wouldn't have to go back and add another statement to the sql clause

Comment: Even here though you'd have to add a new left join for each new page/table.